# Load Date Column from raw data with '/' separator in sparkSQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have columns with data type DATE in sparkSQL
e.g.
 `CREATE TABLE ABC(startDate DATE, EndDate DATE....`
and I load data as 
`LOAD DATA INPATH './input/user.txt' INTO TABLE ABC`

In user.txt data is like

```
2016/06/12 2016/06/15 
2016/06/12 2016/06/15
```

but it loads data as

```
null null
null null
```

if it's

```
2016-06-12 2016-06-15 
2016-06-12 2016-06-15
```

then it takes the data correctly.
How to handle data when the date separator is '/ '?
I don't want to replace the separator in input file.
Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: i think you should use date conversion functions (to cast the strings as date) in the load script.

Comment: Are you planning to use any date time functions on Start and End data fields?

Comment: @vkp I tried to insert data using CAST( startDate as DATE) into other table but still it put null value.

Comment: @dheee yes, I plan to use time functions later like (endDate - startDate) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this issue before in Hive. I found a workaround for this. First load them as string instead of Data type DATE

ex:

```
CREATE TABLE ABC(startDate string, EndDate string....)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ']'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION './input/user.txt';
```

Then i used string functions to extract date/month/year from above fields. For example

```
select substr(date,1,4) as year,substr(date,6,1) as month .... from ABC
```

one other way is to replace the '/' with '-' and then cast them as DATE type and use Date functions

example

```
select regexp_replace(startDate,'/','-') from ABC
```

All the above is how to achieve it in Hive. To work on this in spark is also to first load them as string in to a dataframe.

```
val s1 = Seq(("2016/06/12", "2016/06/15" ), ("2016/06/12", "2016/06/15")).toDF("x", "y")
val result = s1.select(regexp_replace($"x","/", "-"),regexp_replace($"y","/", "-")).show()

result 
+----------+----------+
| startDate|   EndDate|
+----------+----------+
|2016-06-12|2016-06-15|
|2016-06-12|2016-06-15|
+----------+----------+
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Replacing the separator while processing data works perfectly. Thank you  @dheee

Answer (score 1):

i know it's kinda late to answer this question but, in **SPARK** you can also include **`dateFormat`** in options while creating a table.
This will convert your date format from 2016/06/12 to 2016-06-12

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ABC (
                startDate DATE,
                EndDate DATE,
                ...
        )
        using txt
        options(
        path "./input/user.txt",
        dateFormat "yyyy/MM/dd"
        )
```

```sql
select startDate, EndDate from ABC
```

result:
| startDate | EndDate  |
|:----------|:---------|
|2016-06-12 |2016-06-15|
|2016-06-12 |2016-06-15|

Answer (score 0):

I found one more way to do it using functions in SparkSQL on Spark 2.0 Preview Version

```
TO_DATE(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(regexp_replace(startDate , '/','-'),'MM-dd-yyyy'))) AS startDate
```